# Jenkins build with parameters job failing, but if I enter no params the job succeeds

Tags: jenkins, cicd

I have a jenkins job, which has the option to build with optional parameters.
If I click build with parameters and do not specify any parameters and click run, the job will succeed entirely.
If I manually enter in some parameters, the job will fail randomly on my integration tests stage, which has nothing to do with the parameters set.  Parameters are only setting type of build, I.E. Prod/Dev.  This just started happening recently, it used to work just fine, maybe an outdated plug in? I am not sure how to troubleshoot as I am not admin of Jenkins.

Answer (score -1):

Oops I entered the wrong param value, my bad

Comment: Maybe just delete the question then?